# Stripe checkout form disappeared when I publish to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, stripe-payments

I create Payment application with this configuration :

```
Stripe checkout form from
```

https://github.com/stripe-samples/react-elements-card-payment

It’s working well from **localhost** but when I publish to Android via

```
npx cap open android
```

or deploying to firebase I’get this form missing, why ?

https://ionic-4-firebase-crud-de-55a43.firebaseapp.com/tab2

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is because the /public-key endpoint is not returning JSON on the deployed firebase function. Do you need to set an environment variable or something on firebase?

Comment: You are right, I have this message from Google Console : *Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()  /public-key:1 * , but how to define it, with the file **env.** may be ?

Comment: I think that the server proxy payment backend is not in **https**, because It's working well on localhost, it is a security issue.